PyWavelet: Convert Magnitude to Amplitude?
From the output values of a wavelet transformation (complex spectrum or the derived magnitude, normalized magnitude or power) I get no conclusion of the amplitudes of the input signals.
How can I reconstruct/calculate the amplitudes of the input signals from the output values (complex spectrum, magnitude, power) of the wavelet transformation?
Example:
Given is a signal combined by two sine waves. Both sine waves have the same amplitude (1.25) but different frequencies (35.0 and 75.0).
Combined Input Signal
Doing a wavelet transformation with PyWavelets using a complex Morlet wavelet (b = 2.5, cf = 2.0) gives us the decomposition/reconstruction of the two signals in form of a scaleogram with samples and scales (latter could be also shown as frequencies). The coloring shows the magnitude, which is calculated by abs(complex_spectrum). The power of the signals could also be shown by **2 of the magnitude, which is not done in the code.
Wavelet transform Scaleogram
A normalization of the magnitude is done by dividing the magnitude with sqrt(scales) so that the equal amplitudes of the input signals are shown as equal magnitudes.
Wavelet transform Scaleogram with normalized magnitude
The maximum values of the magnitude or norm magnitude are 4.72 or 0.62 respectively--so the values are different from the amplitudes (1.25) of the input signals.
My guess is there should be a scaling based on the variables of the used wavelet, because altering the centre frequency or the bandwidth of the Morlet wavelet alters the output values of the transformation.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pywt

samples = 1000
dt = 1.0 / 1000

ampl1 = 1.25
freq1 = 35.0

ampl2 = 1.25
freq2 = 75.0

x: np.ndarray = np.arange(0, samples) * dt
signal = ampl1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq1 * x) + ampl2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq2 * x)

plt.plot(x, signal)
plt.show()

scales = np.arange(1, 100)

complex_sp, frequencies = pywt.cwt(signal, scales, "cmor2.5-2.0", dt)

magnitude = abs(complex_sp)

plt.imshow(magnitude, cmap="hot", aspect="auto")
plt.colorbar(label="Magnitude")
plt.xlabel("Samples")
plt.ylabel("Scales")
plt.show()

sqrt_scales = np.sqrt(scales)
norm_magnitude = np.divide(magnitude, sqrt_scales[:,None])
plt.imshow(norm_magnitude, cmap="hot", aspect="auto")
plt.colorbar(label="normalized Magnitude")
plt.xlabel("Samples")
plt.ylabel("Scales")
plt.show()

print(np.max(magnitude))
print(np.max(norm_magnitude))

